# Mystery error with CFQUERYPARAM in sub-query

Tags: sql-server-2008, coldfusion

I'm getting an usual error from SQL Server on a query with a subquery, where there is a `CFQUERYPARAM` in the subquery.

The specific error is:

> [Macromedia][SequeLink JDBC Driver][ODBC Socket][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error

I've been able to distill it down to this query (simplified)

```
<cfquery name="statusQuery" datasource="#application.dsn#">
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    BStatus A  
WHERE 
    A.FY = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="2012" > 
    AND 
    A.BStatus like '0%' 
    AND 
    A.BStatus != '00' 
    AND 
    A.BDate = (
            SELECT 
                MAX(B.BDate) 
            FROM BStatus B 
            WHERE 
                B.FY = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="2012" > 
                AND 
                B.BStatus like '0%' 
                AND 
                B.BTrack = A.BTrack 
                AND 
                B.BCode = A.BCode 
    ) 
    AND 
    A.BCode ='XYZ123AB' 
</cfquery>
```

The FY column is defined as `decimal(4,0)`. I've tried every `cfsqltype` that deals with numbers (cf_sql_integer, cf_sql_numeric, cf_sql_real, cf_sql_float, etc.) and they all give the same result.

If I change the `CFQUERYPARAM` in the subquery to just a straight-up value (e.g., 2012) the query works fine. Obviously I would greatly **prefer** to use the `CFQUERYPARAM`.

- ColdFusion 9.0
- SQL Server 2008

Unfortunately, due to other circumstances I can't use the SQL Server drivers that ship with ColdFusion, but must use the ODBC bridge. The database is defined as a System DSN.

Is the ODBC bridge the cause here? I've had `CFQUERYPARAM` in subqueries on past projects so this is really throwing me.

Comment: try by assigning 2012 to a variable and use that variable in cfqueryparam. trythe same using cf_sql_numeric/cf_sql_integer

Comment: The cfsqltype attribute isn't mandatory, try removing it and see if that makes any difference

Comment: @user508518: Done that. It was originally a variable and I changed it to a constant to simplify testing.

Comment: @duncan: Thanks, but that doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, the key appears to be the ODBC bridge. I set up a different datasource using the SQL Server driver and I was able to use `CFQUERYPARAM` in a subquery with no trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a different cfsqltype yet?  I would try cf_sql_integer and also cf_sql_varchar and see if either of those work.  I've never used _decimal; I've used _float, however.

Comment: I tried all the ones that dealt with a number. I'll add that to the question.